# Checking the equality of two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What's Pythonic way of Checking the equality of two dataframes?

What I'm currently doing:

1. Sorting the data frames by a column that has unique values with pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()
2. Resetting the index after data frame is sorted using pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()
3. Sorting the data frames index along row and columns with pandas.DataFrame.sort_index()
4. Then comparing the two data frames with each other and using pandas.DataFrame.all()

An example code :

```
(df1.sort_values(['Symbol']).reset_index(drop=True).sort_index(axis=0).sort_index(axis=1) == 
df2.sort_values(['Symbol']).reset_index(drop=True).sort_index(axis=0).sort_index(axis=1)).all().all()
```

This works, but I feel there should be a better way in doing the same, is there a 'Pythonic Way'?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplier is [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) - default it is by all columns with `inner` join and last [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2).equals(df1)
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,2],
                   'B':[4,6,5],
                   'C':[7,9,8]})[['C','B','A']]
print (df2)
   C  B  A
0  7  4  1
1  9  6  3
2  8  5  2

print (pd.merge(df1, df2))
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

print (pd.merge(df1, df2).equals(df1))
True
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, the above method will fail if the rows are repeated, i.e. we have duplicate rows.

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,7,8,9]})

print (df1)

print (pd.merge(df1, df1).equals(df1))

Comment: I think you are right, duplicates complicated solutions. You can use `print (pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), df1.drop_duplicates()).equals(df1.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)))`

Comment: also works `print (pd.merge(df1, df1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).equals(df1.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))) `

Comment: The catch is, the data can have duplicates and I can't drop them :|

Comment: Adding the below for future reference for others: [Doc on Merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).  If a key combination appears more than once in both tables, the resulting table will have the Cartesian product of the associated data.

Comment: Hmmm, I am thinkong about it. There is not problem if only some columns are same, so drop_duplicates cannot delete them? If yes, then checking can be 2 steps - first check if same index and columns and if yes, then remove duplicates and merge. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

## New Answer

Consider dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
    ], ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y'])

d2 = pd.DataFrame([
        [4, 3],
        [2, 1]
    ], ['B', 'A'], ['Y', 'X'])

(d1.reindex(columns=d2.columns).values[:, None]
     == d2.values).all(-1).any(-1).all()

True
```

## Old Answer

Consider dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
    ], ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y'])

d2 = pd.DataFrame([
        [4, 3],
        [2, 1]
    ], ['B', 'A'], ['Y', 'X'])
```

You want to reindex one like the other and use `pd.DataFrame.equals`

```
d1.reindex_like(d2).equals(d2)

True
```